# React/Typescript : how to type a value in a setter with onChange

Tags: reactjs, typescript, select, onchange, setter

i'm new with react/typescript and i have a problem to "type" a value with an Onchange.
here's the code :

```
    interface Props {
  race : CharacterRace | '',
  classe : CharacterClass | '',
  sexe : CharacterGender | '',
  setRace : (race : CharacterRace | '')=>void,
  setClasse : (classe : CharacterClass | '')=>void,
  setSexe : (sexe: CharacterGender | '')=>void
}
...
          <select name="race" id="race" value={props.race} onChange={({ target: { value } })=>props.setRace(value)}>
        <option value=""> </option>
        <option value="humains">Humain</option>
        <option value="elfes">Elfe</option>
        <option value="orcs">Orc</option>
        <option value="mort-vivants">Mort-Vivant</option>
        <option value="nains">Nain</option>
      </select>
```

He told me that "value" is a string and can't be assigned to CharacterRace | ''

if I make this :

```
 setClasse : (classe : CharacterClass | string)=>void,
```

That "solve" the problem, but it's just a hack, it's not clean

I try to type the "value" but it didn't work

Do you have an idea how I can fix that ?

The type :

```
    export type CharacterRace = 'humains' | 'elfes' | 'orcs' | 'mort-vivants' | 'nains';

    export type CharacterClass = 'guerrier' | 'barbare' | 'paladin' | 'rodeur' | 'voleur' | 'mage' | 'pretre' | 'guerrier-mage';
    
    export type CharacterGender = 'masculin' | 'feminin';
```

Comment: Can you post the typings for CharacterRace?

Comment: We need to see the declaration of CharacterClass before being able to actually fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "HTMLInputElement"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).